# Read/write blocks to file in assembly

Tags: assembly, masm

I have to write code that is supposed to read the text from a `.txt` file in 64-byte blocks, encrypt each block and then write it to another `.txt` file. For now I want to be able to read 64-byte blocks and write them without any change to the destination file. I am aware that there are quite a few problems with my code but I can't figure out how to solve them so any help and suggestions are very much appreciated. Here is what I managed to do.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall

includelib msvcrt.lib
extern exit: proc
extern printf: proc
extern scanf: proc
extern fscanf: proc
extern fprintf: proc
extern fopen: proc
extern fclose: proc

public start


.data

  type_read db "r",0

  type_write db "w", 0

  destination db "destination.txt",0      ;name of destination file
  fscanf_format db "%lld",0 
  fprintf_format db "%lld",0

  msg_start db "Source file path:",0

  source dd 0  ;name of source file
  source_format db "%s", 0
  block64 dq 0
  pointer_source db 0
  pointer_destination dd 0

.code

start:
    mov eax,0
    push offset msg_start
    call printf
    add esp,4

    ; read name source file
    push  offset source
    push offset source_format
    call scanf
    add esp,8

    ; open source file
    push offset type_read
    push offset sursa
    call fopen
    add esp,8
    mov pointer_source,eax  ;save source pointer eax

    ; open destination file
    push offset type_write
    push offset destination
    call fopen
    add esp,8
    mov pointer_destination,ebx

    reading:
    ;file reading
    push    offset block64           ;offset of qword variable
    push    offset fscanf_format     ;format string "%lld",0
    push    pointer_source            ;file pointer
    call    fscanf
    add     esp,16

    ;i tried to write what i've read to file destination.txt but i am not sure how to
    pop     ebx
    sub     esp,8

    cmp eax,0ffffffffh;end of file?
    je finish
    end reading

    finish:
    push 0
    call exit
    end finish

end start
```

Comment: Your question is in danger of being closed.  You may want to re-read the instructions on how to properly ask a question, especially when it comes to clearly describing the problem and what you've done so far.  "This doesn't work, tell me why" isn't even close to that. :)

Comment: Obviously this is homework.  Are you supposed to be using just the C library?  If so, then use fopen/fread/frwite for I/O on the binary file.  scanf/fscanf parses the input data, so you only want to use it for getting the filename (or better, take the filename as a commandline arg).

Comment: @DavidHoelzer OP provided a description of what the program was to do, full source code [mostly working, AFAICT], and in a code comment delineated which line specifically he was having problems with.  If he had elevated the comment to the post top things would be fine.  But, to any asm person, there is already enough info to give an answer [and he got one].  As 1-point postings go, I've seen far worse.

Comment: @CraigEstey I am an assembly person.  I shouldn't have to slog through code to figure out what, "I am aware that there are quite a few problems with my code but I can't figure out how to solve them" means.  That's not a clear problem statement to me. :)  Sorry if I offended.

Comment: What I do question is the 3rd party (David Tansey) that came through and changed 64-bit blocks to 64-byte blocks. If it had been the OP making the change I could possibly understand. It is a bit unclear to me what the original question the OP wanted answered.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Some 1-pt Qs _are_ terrible [OP made no effort and is non-responsive]--they deserve close. I can understand your frustration. Here, IMO, OP is newbie to SO _and_ asm and did his best--came up a bit short.  In this latter case, I usually ask specific questions--sometimes OP edits Q accordingly and it becomes fully formed.  I've also had a Q about disk recovery [sys non-bootable] closed as off-topic while I'm answering [without migration].  yes, off-topic, but maybe dire straits deserve leeway?  OP's only mistake was wrong site [while in a panic] but SO better known than superuser

Comment: I am sorry if I broke any rules, I really tried my best to explain what I am supposed to do and what it is not working. I've written the code by myself ,but based on different examples/tutorials and I hoped someone would know why it is not properly working. I did not ask for someone to solve it for me, I just wanted advice/suggestions on what I've written. If it was not the place to ask I am sorry again for rule braking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update, question was changed from 64 bit blocks to 64 byte blocks, apparently by a third person (see comments after question, or look at edit history). Two examples below, one for 64 bit using fscanf / fprintf, one for 64 byte block using fread / fwrite.

Which encryption scheme is to be used was not explained. This could affect the number of bytes per block, such as AES, which does 16 byte blocks (smaller blocks have to be padded to 16 bytes).

Working example using Microsoft masm (ml.exe) for 64 bit copy.

```
        .data
block64 dd      0,0                     ;two dd's for 64 bits
pointer_source dd 0                     ;source FILE * value
pointer_destination dd 0                ;dest   FILE * value

msg_start   db "Source file path:",0
source      db "                "       ;name of source file (read in)
destination db "destination.txt",0      ;name of destination file
fscanf_format db "%lld",0 
fprintf_format db "%lld",10,0           ;added new line
source_format db "%s", 0
type_read db "r",0
type_write db "w", 0
        .code
        ; ...
        push    offset msg_start
        call    printf
        add     esp,4

        ; read name source file
        push    offset source
        push    offset source_format
        call    scanf
        add     esp,8

        ; open source file
        push    offset type_read
        push    offset source
        call    fopen
        add     esp,8
        mov     pointer_source,eax      ;save source FILE *

        ; open destination file
        push    offset type_write
        push    offset destination
        call    fopen
        add     esp,8
        mov     pointer_destination,eax ;save destination FILE *

reading:
        push    offset block64
        push    offset fscanf_format
        mov     eax,pointer_source      ;push file pointer value
        push    eax
        call    fscanf
        add     esp,12                  ;restore esp
        cmp     eax,0ffffffffh          ;br if end of file
        je      finish
        mov     eax,block64+4           ;push 64 bit block
        push    eax                     ;   
        mov     eax,block64             ;
        push    eax                     ;
        push    offset fprintf_format   ;push ptr to format string
        mov     eax,pointer_destination ;push file pointer value
        push    eax                     ;
        call    fprintf                 ;print value
        add     esp,16                  ;restore esp
        jmp     short reading           ;short is optional
;
finish:
        mov     eax,pointer_destination ;push file pointer value
        push    eax                     ;
        call    fclose                  ;close file
        add     esp,4
        mov     eax,pointer_source      ;push file pointer value
        push    eax
        call    fclose                  ;close file
        add     esp,4
        push    dword ptr 0             ;(masm needs dword ptr)
        call    exit
```

Example for 64 byte block copy.

```
        .data
block64 db      64 dup (0)              ;64 byte buffer
pointer_source dd 0                     ;source FILE * value
pointer_destination dd 0                ;dest   FILE * value

msg_start   db "Source file path:",0
source      db "                "       ;name of source file (read in)
destination db "destination.txt",0      ;name of destination file
source_format db "%s", 0
type_read db "rb",0                     ;read binary
type_write db "wb", 0                   ;write binary
        .code
        ; ...
        push    offset msg_start
        call    printf
        add     esp,4

        ; read name source file
        push    offset source
        push    offset source_format
        call    scanf
        add     esp,8

        ; open source file
        push    offset type_read
        push    offset source
        call    fopen
        add     esp,8
        mov     pointer_source,eax      ;save source FILE *

        ; open destination file
        push    offset type_write
        push    offset destination
        call    fopen
        add     esp,8
        mov     pointer_destination,eax ;save destination FILE *

reading:
        mov     eax,pointer_source      ;push FILE * value
        push    eax
        push    dword ptr 64            ;count
        push    dword ptr 1             ;size
        push    offset block64          ;ptr to buffer
        call    fread                   ;read 64 bytes (or less)
        add     esp,16                  ;restore esp
        test    eax,eax                 ;br if end file
        je      finish
        mov     ebx,pointer_destination ;push file pointer value (ebx)
        push    ebx                     ;
        push    eax                     ;count
        push    dword ptr 1             ;size
        push    offset block64          ;ptr to buffer
        call    fwrite                  ;write 64 bytes (or less)
        add     esp,16                  ;restore esp
        jmp     short reading           ;short is optional
;
finish:
        mov     eax,pointer_destination ;push file pointer value
        push    eax                     ;
        call    fclose                  ;close file
        add     esp,4
        mov     eax,pointer_source      ;push file pointer value
        push    eax
        call    fclose                  ;close file
        add     esp,4
        push    dword ptr 0
        call    exit
```

Comment: Any idea why this was downvoted [not by me]?  Was it lack of verbiage outside of the code explaining how the code was changed from OP's?  Or, because it was perceived as answering a homework assignment [the bulk of which, the crypto, to be written]?  You've added enough code comments where things should be clear.

Comment: Downvotes without comments - useless feature of SO. I don't care anymore about these. It's a working example (I tested this).

Comment: I'm sure you did and you've been suitably rewarded ;-)

Comment: Nothing worse than comment less down votes.  I wish we could down vote the down votes.

Comment: The question was changed from 64 bit blocks to 64 byte blocks by a third person (see comments for the original question or look at edit history). I gave examples of both. Maybe the downvote was related to 64 bit / byte confusion, it's gone now.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me understand/fix my code. I am obviously a newbie, and I really appreciate you taking your time. Thanks.

Comment: For encryption I will calculate ones' complement for each 64-bit block and then xor it with the encryption key.

Comment: @CraigEstey :I thought this was familiar.You sure it was Jester and not rcgldr? I was actually the downvoter.I downvoted from my smartphone where it was a pain to leave a comment. At the time the question and the answer were not in sync. One was for 64-bit and one was 64-bytes. The issue was that  a third party altered the question and the answer didn't match the question. Later that was fixed at which time I removed the downvote and actually upvoted. Had I not been on my smartphone when I read the question and answer, I would have left a comment here. I hinted at this issue under the question

Comment: @CraigEstey : You should assume that people have their reasons for not actually downvoting and not leaving a reason. It may be circumstance. When the ambiguity between bit and byte was finally fleshed out, later in the day I returned and removed the downvote. It was also noted in the comments above that it disappeared. I then upvoted. Don't assume that all downvotes are done with no thought, and don't assume that once a downvote is done there is no attempt to come back and see if things changed that may change the vote. Be concerned about your votes, not others.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, this was it. Here, I was just asking why to rcgldr [and he gave me the reason within 45 mins]. Unfortunate that you weren't able to leave a comment initially. Michael, you are diligent and thoughtful [and I knew this then]. But, [many--too many] others aren't. I've seen downvotes for arbitrary, uninformed, snarky, and, yes, even spiteful reasons--those deserve at least a comment. None of that applies to you. To me, commenting on a downvote is no better or worse than commenting on a comment. Once again, sorry if you got tarred with the same brush.